# Is .NET Framework 4.0 installed as part of Visual Studio 2010 install?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I know .NET Framework 4.0 is available as separate install but...

Is .NET Framework 4.0 installed as a part of Visual Studio 2010 Professional or does VS 2010 install prompt for 4.0 install at all or not?

Should it be a separate install, should it matter if installed before or after of VS install?

I want to know this for documentation purpose. My search on internet failed to return satisfactory results.

**Edit:**

Then what about prior versions(2.0, 3.5)? Are they installed as well? Because VS 2010 supports those versions as well for development.

Thanks for prompt answers guys.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its installed automatically as a prerequisite for VS2010.. definitely compulsory!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is a list of all the prerequisites installed with Visual Studio 2010 >
[prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tx0bw8y.aspx)

.Net Framework 3.5 (install also includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) and .Net Framework 4.0 are on the list and installed by default.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course .NET 4.0 is installed with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. The VS2010 installer checks for the presence of .NET 4.0 and installs it if it can't find it. The framework has to be installed prior to the installation of VS 2010 itself.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. How could VS2010 support coding against .NET 4.0 if it wasn't installed?